# How to set up my nodejs backend via docker so that the database is built with the proper tables?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

This might be jumbled up so I'm going to discuss my whole set up accordingly as well as describe my goal.

I'm developing an api using Node.js/Express. I've integrated docker so that when anyone tries to run the application they'd only need to run the command `docker compose up`

The way the command is set up is via a dockerfile + docker-compose.yml

the docker-compose.yml contains the following

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mainDB
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  api:
    image: api
    depends_on: 
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

This sets up the docker container to have both the api and the database running together but the issue arises when I try to connect to the database.

I have an sql file that contains the following

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruits;

CREATE TABLE fruits (
    fruitID INTEGER primary key,
    fruitName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fruitColor VARCHAR(255),
);
```

I'm currently unable to connect to the database via pgAdmin and the error I'm getting is that the database name I'm referencing doesn't exist ("mainDB"). When I enter into psql via my terminal it also doesn't show the existence of a database either.

My overall confusion is this: how can I set this up so that when the command `docker compose up` is executed, the user is able to have both the api and the database running with the table created in the database as well?

Is this feasible? From what I've seen on tutorials is people having these sql files and just copy and pasting the commands into the psql command line. What would be the point of having the database running in the `docker-compose.yml` file if I'd have to manually build it from my psql command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in setup the database for the application when creating the container, you can use PostgreSQL's `Initialization Scripts`.

You can mount any number of scripts on the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`  folder that PostgreSQL will run when booting up on an empty dir.

Based on your current setup and the best practices recommended on the PostgreSQL image documentation, you could do something like this:

First, write a script that generates the user, database, and all its tables. Wrapping it like this will avoid a pervasive error when there's a failure on one of the init scripts and the container is restarted.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;

    CREATE TABLE fruits (
        fruitID INTEGER primary key,
        fruitName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        fruitColor VARCHAR(255),
    );
EOSQL
```

Then mount this script to the appropriate folder by updating your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mainDB
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # Suppose the SQL file you provided was on the same folder as 
      # the docker-compose file.
      - ./fruits.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001-fruits.sh
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  api:
    image: api
    depends_on: 
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

PostgreSQL will run the init scripts provided in alphabetical order. So, if you need them to run on a certain sequence, you should prefix them with an order number.

You should see the schema is now available on the database.

Check the PostgreSQL image documentation site for more information:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used what you said but tweaked it slightly by using an sql file instead of an sh file. Your answer definitely cleared things up + the info I got from this medium article.

https://onexlab-io.medium.com/docker-compose-postgres-initdb-ba0021deef76